# Incorrectly checks criteria for movement of a player's "penguin" on the board

Tags: c

The criteria for moving to a spot is that it doesn't have a penguin on it, isn't a 0 tile (water spot), and isn't off the board. If the player choses a direction that would defy the criteria, they should be asked to re-enter their direction.

I made created a for loop that loops through pengs of players, and based on if the user inputs u,d,l,r for their direction, the peng's row & column will change accordingly. The result is that sometimes, without a pattern I've yet to identify), the wrong penguin is moved or the "you cant move there" message is displayed, when you can actually move there.

How do I fix the movement phase so it moves the penguins properly, and ends the game when no one else can move any penguins?

```
void getPengPos(struct board *gameBoard, int playerIndex, int *row, int *column) {
    for (int i = 0; i < gameBoard->rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < gameBoard->columns; j++) {
            if (gameBoard->penguins[i * gameBoard->columns + j] == 'A' + playerIndex) {
                *row = i;
                *column = j;
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    *row = -1;
    *column = -1;
}

void movementPhase(struct board *gameBoard, Player players[], int num_players, int num_pengwings, int board_height, int board_width) {
    char direction;
    bool validInput = false;

    int playerRow, playerCol;
    int i, x;

    for (x = 0; x < num_pengwings; x++) {
        for (i = 0; i < num_players; i++) {
            validInput = false;

            while (!validInput) {
                printf("Player %d, Enter how you want to move penguin %d (u, d, r, l): ", i+1, x+1);
                scanf(" %c", &direction);

                getPengPos(gameBoard, i, &playerRow, &playerCol);

                if (direction == 'u') {
                    if (playerRow-1 > 0 && playerRow-1 <= board_width) {
                        validInput = true;
                        gameBoard->penguins[playerRow * gameBoard->columns + playerCol] = ' ';
                        playerRow--;
                        gameBoard->penguins[playerRow * gameBoard->columns + playerCol] = 'A' + i;
                        printBoard(gameBoard);
                    } else {
                        printf("You can't move that penguin up, you're already at the top of the board! Try again.\n");
                    }
                } else if (direction == 'd') {
                    if (playerRow+1 > 0 && playerRow+1 <= board_width) {
                        validInput = true;
                        gameBoard->penguins[playerRow * gameBoard->columns + playerCol] = ' ';
                        playerRow++;
                        gameBoard->penguins[playerRow * gameBoard->columns + playerCol] = 'A' + i;
                        printBoard(gameBoard);
                    } else {
                        printf("You can't move that penguin down, you're already at the bottom of the board! Try again.\n");
                    }
                } else if (direction == 'r') {
                    if (playerCol+1 > 0 && playerCol+1 <= board_height) {
                        validInput = true;
                        gameBoard->penguins[playerRow * gameBoard->columns + playerCol] = ' ';
                        playerCol++;
                        gameBoard->penguins[playerRow * gameBoard->columns + playerCol] = 'A' + i;
                        printBoard(gameBoard);
                    } else {
                        printf("You can't move that penguin to the right, it'll fall off the board! Try again.\n");
                    }
                } else if (direction == 'l') {
                    if (playerCol-1 > 0 && playerCol-1 <= board_height) {
                        validInput = true;
                        gameBoard->penguins[playerRow * gameBoard->columns + playerCol] = ' ';
                        playerCol--;
                        gameBoard->penguins[playerRow * gameBoard->columns + playerCol] = 'A' + i;
                        printBoard(gameBoard);
                    } else {
                        printf("You can't move that penguin to the left, it'll fall off the board! Try again.\n");
                    }
                } else {
                    printf("Invalid entry, please make sure to input only u, d, r, or l.\n");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: With `u`, for example: `if (playerRow-1 > 0 && playerRow-1 <= board_width) {` Why do you need that 2nd condition?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: You may also want to consider unit tests, static analysis, and building with sanitizers enabled.  And, if you're not already, crank up your compiler's warnings as high as you can.

Comment: The variable names are a bit weird. I would have expected rows to be limited by board height, and columns to be limited by board width. Also watch out for off-by-one programming errors in the comparisons.

Comment: ... especially since moving up or down changes the row, and moving left or right changes the column.